# Broken stroke falloff in Photoshop 2020

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing-tablet, wacom

I'm trying to create strokes with a Wacom Intuos tablet but the brush size falloff seems to be completely broken. Despite diameter control set to *“pen pressure”* and minimum diameter to *0* I still can't achieve sharp strokes.

Just to clarify that **the issue is not with my tablet**, here's a comparison between any other illustration soft (left) and Photoshop 2020 (right):
[image]

For some reason, it seems like falloff in Photoshop never reaches 0, even though settings specify it.
Reinstalling didn't do much.
Any ideas?

Hopefully a bump.
I tried reinstalling Photoshop, and Wacom drivers multiple time with no results. I'd like to mention once again that **the issue is not with the tablet as Photoshop uses default preset. In fact, Photoshop refuses to use its own preset and ignores it whenever I try to add it, instead using action keys and pressure settings from default.**

Comment: You *sure* it's not an issue with the tablet... seeing as the tablet itself *can* have individual application settings. I can easily set the tablet to use a soft touch in AI and a firm touch in PS... all in the tablet preferences...

Comment: "Photoshop refuses to use its own preset and ignores" what are you talking about? Nothing is broken, you have to find a balance of tablet settings and a driver that suits your needs (windows ink vs wintab)